# Does page speed insight ignore pages with no index, no follow tags added to discouage bots from crawling

Tags: chrome-ux-report

Does page speed insight ignore pages with no index, no follow tags added to discouage bots from crawling.
If not, is there a way to make google ignore a page from the origin data summary (Field data).

Comment: This is nothing to do with Page Speed Insights as the data is from the Chrome User Experience Report (CrUX data set). I have changed the tag for you. I did have a look but I cannot confirm if this conforms to robots configuration as the data is from real world users....my guess is if people are actually accessing a page then it will be included and I think that would be the right way to do it otherwise you could just exclude poor performing pages rather than fix them, however that last part is just pure speculation on my part!

Comment: Exactly your answer's last part is the open point of the question. We have actually added no index, no follow rule to the page because customers need not see it, only our physical store associates need to see it. Just exclude it from search. But if pagespeed insights considers this in its evaluation, then is that fair?

Answer (score 2):

Pages that explicitly opt out of indexing should **not** have URL-level field data in PSI or the CrUX API. However, those pages may still be included in the origin-level performance distribution.